# How to sum specific elements in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sum elements in an array. For example I have an array

```
[183948, 218520, 243141, 224539, 205322, 203855, 233281, 244830, 281245,
 280579, 235384, 183596, 106072,  88773,  63297,  38769,  28343]
```

I want to sum it in three different parts which are the first three elements, the next 10 elements and the rest.
 My only idea is to separate the array and use sum method. Is there better way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Slice the array and sum the slices. Since it seems your partitioning of the array is arbitrary, there's not going to be a truly elegant solution. Perhaps you can put your slice indices into a list and use a `for` loop to go through them

Comment: slice and sum is best way

Comment: Got it, this is what I was thinking too

Comment: @roganjosh have you answered my question before? your name seems familiar?

Comment: My name probably is familiar; I spend too much time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
arr=[183948, 218520, 243141, 224539, 205322, 203855, 233281, 244830, 281245,
 280579, 235384, 183596, 106072,  88773,  63297,  38769,  28343]

first=arr[0:3]
second=arr[3:13]
last=arr[13:]

print(sum(first))
print(sum(second))
print(sum(last))
```

the alternative more extensible version is as follows

```
arr=[183948, 218520, 243141, 224539, 205322, 203855, 233281, 244830, 281245,
 280579, 235384, 183596, 106072,  88773,  63297,  38769,  28343]

indices=[3,13]
results=[]
prev=0
for i in indices:
    results.append(sum(arr[prev:i]))
    prev=i
results.append(sum(arr[prev:]))

for res in results:
    print(res)
```

note: set prev = to the index you want to start from, in this case 0

Comment: I think this is the only way, but a vast improvement would be having the indices in a list and iterating with a `for` loop. This is hard-coded.

Comment: that works too but i think for only 3 slices this is ok. if he had more slice points then that way would def be alot better tho

Comment: Ok, but would it not be better to post an extensible answer? What if someone else comes along that has 10 slices?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduceat` method of `np.add`:

```
data = [183948, 218520, 243141, 224539, 205322, 203855, 233281, 244830, 281245,
 280579, 235384, 183596, 106072,  88773,  63297,  38769,  28343]

sizes = 3, 10

np.add.reduceat(data, np.cumsum([0, *sizes]))
# array([ 645609, 2198703,  219182])
```

Comment: What should I do if sizes is zero? e.g. sizes = 3, 0, 10
which returns array([ 645609,  224539, 2198703,  219182]), even though the desired result would be array([ 645609,  0, 2198703,  219182])